# Xcode 10.1 : Provisioning profile signing certificate error

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Xcode 10.1 shows error while archive the build. I have installed Xcode 10.1 in my mac machine. Xcode shows:

> "Provisioning profile does not include the iphone developer certificates".

I have created all the certificates and installed in my mac. Can anyone please let me know to fix the issues.

Comment: Did you update old provisioning profile with new certificate? install iPhone configure utility . It will show all the provisioing profile in listing

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic issue.

There are several ways to fix this, **like enabling automatic signing etc (Recommended)**. But if you want to understand the reason for this error you need to look at the error message.

It says that the provisioning profile you have selected in the "General tab", does not contain the signing certificate you selected in the "Build settings" -> "Code Signing Identity".

Usually this happens if a distribution certificate has been selected for the debug identity under "Build settings" -> "Code Signing Identity".

If this happens under "Signing (Debug)" it might also be that the "Signing Identity" -> "iOS Development" is not included in the provisioning profile.

[image]

Comment: Actually i have downloaded and installed the certificates. Can you please tell me the steps to include the signing certificates?

Comment: Double click, simple as that!

Comment: I have did the same what you said. But nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your provisional profile and its related certificate from **Signing** into **Build Setting**.

Check attached screenshots[image] for same.

Comment: In my build setting also we have the settings like the above. But it shows the signing certficates doesn't included. Can you please tell me to add signing certificate into xcode